# Need an aggregate MySQL select that iterates virtually across date ranges and returns bills

Tags: mysql, dynamic, aggregation

I have a MySQL table named rbsess with columns RBSessID (key), ClientID (int), RBUnitID (int), RentAmt (fixed-point int), RBSessStart (DateTime), and PrevID (int, references to RBSessID).

It's not transactional or linked.  What it does track when a client was moved into a room and what the rent at the time of move in was.  The query to find what the rent was for a particular client on a particular date is:

```
SET @DT='Desired date/time'
SET @ClientID=Desired client id

SELECT a.RBSessID
     , a.ClientID
     , a.RBUnitID
     , a.RentAmt
     , a.RBSessStart
     , b.RBSessStart AS RBSessEnd
     , a.PrevID 
  FROM rbsess a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN rbsess b 
    ON b.PrevID=a.RBSessID 
 WHERE a.ClientID=@ClientID 
   AND (a.RBSessStart<=@DT OR a.RBSessStart IS NULL) 
   AND (b.RBSessStart>@DT OR b.RBSessStart IS NULL);
```

This will output something like:

```
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------+
| RBSessID | ClientID | RBUnitID | RentAmt | RBSessStart         | RBSessEnd | PrevID |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------+
|        2 |        4 |        1 |   57500 | 2020-11-22 00:00:00 | NULL      |      1 |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------+
```

I also have

```
SELECT * FROM rbsess WHERE rbsess.ClientID=@ClientID AND rbsess.PrevID IS NULL; //for finding the first move in date
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,@DT,LAST_DAY(@DT)) AS CountDays; //for finding the number of days until the end of the month
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(@DT)) AS MaxDays;  //for finding the number of days in the month
SELECT (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,@DT,LAST_DAY(@DT))+1)/DAY(LAST_DAY(@DT)) AS ProRateRatio; //for finding the ratio to calculate the pro-rated rent for the move-in month
SELECT ROUND(40000*(SELECT (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,@DT,LAST_DAY(@DT))+1)/DAY(LAST_DAY(@DT)) AS ProRateRatio)) AS ProRatedRent; //for finding a pro-rated rent amount based on a rent amount.
```

I'm having trouble putting all of these together to form a single query that can output pro-rated and full rent amounts based on a start date and an optional end date all rent owed amounts in a single statement for each month in the period.  I can add a payments table received and integrate it afterwards, just having a hard time with this seemingly simple real-world concept in a MySQL query.  I'm using php with a MySQL back end.  Temporary tables as intermediary queries are more than acceptable.

Even a nudge would be helpful.  I'm not super-experienced with MySQL queries, just your basic CREATE, SELECT, INSERT, DROP, and UPDATE.

Examples as requested by GMB:

```
//Example data in rbsess table:
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+--------+
| RBSessID | ClientID | RBUnitID | RentAmt | RBSessStart         | PrevID |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+--------+
|        1 |        4 |        1 |   40000 | 2020-10-22 00:00:00 |   NULL |
|        2 |        4 |        1 |   57500 | 2020-11-22 00:00:00 |      1 |
|        3 |        2 |        5 |   40000 | 2020-11-29 00:00:00 |   NULL |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+--------+
```

Expected results would be a list of the rent amounts owed for every month, including pro-rated amounts for partial occupancy in a month, from a date range of months.  For example for the example data above for a date range spanning all of the year of 2020 from client with ClientID=4 the query would produce an amount for each month within the range similar to:

```
Month     | Amt
2020-10-1 | 12903
2020-11-1 | 45834
2020-12-1 | 57500
```

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad. Please provide sample data from the related table, and desired results.

Comment: @GMB  I've done as you requested, provided example data and an expected query result.